# Unrecognized column from wildcard table

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to query for the same aggregate stat over all tables matching some naming scheme:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(CONCAT('20', _TABLE_SUFFIX), 0, 10) AS date,
  CASE
    WHEN ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 'mobile') THEN 'mobile'
    ELSE 'desktop'
  END AS client,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(bytesJS,1000)[OFFSET(500)] AS p50
FROM
  `httparchive.runs.20*`
WHERE
  ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages')
  OR ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages_mobile')
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2
```

However, the query is failing with `Error: Unrecognized name: bytesJS at [7:20]`

There should be about 150 tables that match the query. Here's the schema for one of these tables: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/httparchive:runs.2017_05_15_pages

`bytesJS` is a valid column name, but it's failing as unrecognized. Same error when substituting different known columns. I'm not sure if this is a direct result of using the table wildcard or what.

I would rewrite this with legacy SQL and see if that works, but my query requires selecting the table metadata.

Is this an incompatibility with the wildcard?

Comment: Also note that removing the APPROX_QUANTILES line produces valid results, so the error is definitely to do with bytesJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version that works:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  SUBSTR(CONCAT('20', _TABLE_SUFFIX), 0, 10) AS date,
  CASE
    WHEN ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 'mobile') THEN 'mobile'
    ELSE 'desktop'
  END AS client,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(bytesJS,1000)[OFFSET(500)] AS p50
FROM
  `httparchive.runs.2017_05_15_pages*`
#WHERE
  #ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages')
  #OR ENDS_WITH(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages_mobile')
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2
```

What's happening:

- `httparchive.runs.20*` encompasses some tables which don't have the `bytesJS` column, hence that column is not considered for the rest of the query.
- By the time the query looks for `(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages') OR (_TABLE_SUFFIX, '_pages_mobile')`, it's too late to change the query assumed schema.

Solution:

- `FROM prefix*` table glob won't work here, you'll have to run a classic UNION of tables.

Comment: Ah I see. So this would be a good reason to split up the runs dataset into pages and requests datasets. It must be the requests tables causing the issue.

Comment: yeah... another "convenient' solution would be to have the type as prefix

Comment: Felipe, do you know if there's a way to use COALESCE or IFNULL to work around the "unrecognized name" issue?